# Error when inserting into relational table many to many

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to persist relational data in myql database with typeORM and nestjs but it's showing an error apparently in the database

Entity:

```js
  @ManyToMany(()=> Stock, stock => stock.seals)
  @JoinTable()
  stock: Stock[];
```

Service:

```js
var c = getConnection().getRepository(Seals).save(createSealDto)
     return c
```

Error:

> ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`stocksystem`.`stock_seals_seals`, CONSTRAINT `FK_70140d58e95fbceed988b224e64` FOREIGN KEY (`stockId`) REFERENCES `stock` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Payload:

```json
{"client":{"id":1},"stock":[{"id":1},{"id":1}],"price":398}
```

Comment: Could it be because you have 2 stocks with the same id (`"id":1`)?